# How can I set the target .Net Framework version (.Net 4.0, or .Net 4.5, or .Net 4.5.1) when I use the tools (csc.exe) manually?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, msbuild, .net-framework-version, csc

Each of .Net Framework version has own versions of `csc.exe`, `msbuild.exe`, etc. On my notebook all .Net Framework versions (newer than .Net 1.0) are installed. I see such directories:

[image: List of the "%WINDIR%\Microsoft.Net\Framework64" subdirectories]

I created some new Windows-variables:

```
%NET30% = "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v3.0"
%NET35% = "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v3.5"
%NET40% = "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319"
```

and use them when I use `csc.exe`, `al.exe` and `msbuild.exe` manually or through the `BAT`-files (from the usual `cmd.exe`). It allows to me compile my code sources on my notebook (it is not a "super car"), which hasn't Visual Studio, but has all necessary .Net Framework versions installed.

For example, I use that variables in my `BAT`-files. Sample:

```
:: (c) Andrey Bushman, 2015
:: Building the .Net-extension for AutoCAD 2009(x86|x64), 2013(AnyCPU), 
:: 2015(AnyCPU) with locating of some functional in the separate netmodule-file.

:: AutoCAD 2009x64
:: 1. module
start /WAIT "AutoCAD 2009x64" %net35%\csc @.\acad2009x64-netmodule.rsp .\Commands.cs .\ExtensionApplication.cs .\ExtensionMethods.cs

:: 2. assembly
start /WAIT "AutoCAD 2009x64" %net35%\csc @.\acad2009x64-entry-point.rsp /addmodule:".\\proxy.R17.2x64.netmodule" .\EntryPoint.cs

:: AutoCAD 2009x86
:: 1. module
start /WAIT "AutoCAD 2009x86" %net35%\csc @.\acad2009x86-netmodule.rsp .\Commands.cs .\ExtensionApplication.cs .\ExtensionMethods.cs

:: 2. assembly
start /WAIT "AutoCAD 2009x86" %net35%\csc @.\acad2009x86-entry-point.rsp /addmodule:".\\proxy.R17.2x86.netmodule" .\EntryPoint.cs

:: AutoCAD 2013
:: 1. module
start /WAIT "AutoCAD 2013" %net40%\csc @.\acad2013-netmodule.rsp .\Commands.cs .\ExtensionApplication.cs .\ExtensionMethods.cs

:: 2. assembly
start /WAIT "AutoCAD 2013" %net40%\csc @.\acad2013-entry-point.rsp /addmodule:".\\proxy.R19.0.netmodule" .\EntryPoint.cs

:: AutoCAD 2015
:: 1. module
start /WAIT "AutoCAD 2015" %net40%\csc @.\acad2015-netmodule.rsp .\Commands.cs .\ExtensionApplication.cs .\ExtensionMethods.cs

:: 2. assembly
start /WAIT "AutoCAD 2015" %net40%\csc @.\acad2015-entry-point.rsp /addmodule:".\\proxy.R20.0.netmodule" .\EntryPoint.cs
```

The same .Net Framework versions are installed on my machine in office. Also this computer has MS Visual Studio.2013 installed. In the IDE I see such list of enabled .Net Framework versions:

[image]

The .Net Framework 4.5, .Net Framework 4.5.1 items exist also...

**My question**: How can I set the target .Net Framework version (.Net 4.0, or .Net 4.5, or .Net 4.5.1) when I use the tools (`csc.exe`) from the `%NET40%` directory on my notebook manually, or in my `BAT`-files? I don't see this option in the `csc.exe /?` output.

Comment: Only the `/reference` options matter.  They must refer to the correct reference assemblies stored in the subdirectories of  the C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies directory.